# Reprojecting MODIS Swath data to WGS84 using GDAL

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, modis, wgs84

Im new to GIS and now working with MODIS04L2 Aerosol Optical Thickness image. I need to reproject the image to other coordinate system such as WGS84 for later work but now Im stuck with it. I have try two ways:

1. Write my own code using python with gdal lib: I follow the tutorial which using GCPs point as paramater for gdalwarp command. The problem is I can't get the GCPs point. The dataset.GetGCPs() function return a zero-length array of GCPs.
2. Using programs like HEG tool, MRT tool but both of it have issues. When I open MODIS file (with extension .hdf) with MRT tool I get the error "Error in Module: ReadHdrFile".

I download MODIS from ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/data/search.html with parameter: Satellite/Instrument:Terra, Group: Terra Atmosphere Level 2 Product, Products: MOD04L2_Leve 2 Aerrosol and Collection: MODIS Collection 5.1. I want to extract subdataset "mod04:Image_Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean" from hdf MODIS file to geotiff which reprojected to WGS84.

The sample hdf file http://sdrv.ms/JpVQNh
The log from gdalinfo:http://sdrv.ms/JpTQok

Anyone here has experiment with this process?

---

It turns out that the gdal package on my computer is out of date so I cannot get the GCPs via gdalinfo. I updated the gdal to 1.10.0 and now everything is working fine.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Where did you download the MODIS, and which particular image set are you using? What have you already looked at (http://modis-atmos.gsfc.nasa.gov/MOD04_L2/spec.html ?) What happens when you use gdalinfo? Do you see GRINGPOINTLATITUDE and GRINGPOINTLONGITUDE?

Comment: I download MODIS from http://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/data/search.html with parameter: Satellite/Instrument:Terra, Group: Terra Atmosphere Level 2 Product, Products: MOD04L2_Leve 2 Aerrosol and Collection: MODIS Collection 5.1. I want to extract subdataset "mod04:Image_Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean" from hdf MODIS file to geotiff which reprojected to WGS84. I updated the log from gdalinfo command above. And yes I see the GRINGPOINTLATITUDE and GRINGPOINTLONGITUDE but dont known what it's for?

Comment: Can you please edit your question, rather than adding comments? That helps us to understand the "whole story" and helps other people. GringPointLatitude and GringPointLongitude give you the geographic bounds of the swath - see http://nrm.salrm.uaf.edu/~dverbyla/MODIS_Land_Products/pdf_documents/users_guides/snow_users_guide.pdf and look for the stuff that is common.

Comment: Thanks @BradHards, I updated the question. As you said, GringPointLatitude and GringPointLongitude give the geographic bounds of the swath, but I still cant see how I could you it for the reprojection. Can I use these points as corresponding to MODIS image corner coordinate as GCPs?

Comment: I believe those are the corner points, so why not use those as part of the warp?

Comment: What software/methods (e.g. Erdas, ENVI, ArcGIS, Python, Matlab, R etc) are you willing to work with?

Comment: Hi @Aaron Python or Linux shell is my preference, but solution for any other software/language is acceptable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need the subdataset full name from the query on the file:

```
gdalinfo MOD04_L2.A2003001.0005.051.2010313005421.hdf >2003.txt
```

With the subdataset name, you get the GCP coordinates in pixel and lon/lat:

```
gdalinfo HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD04_L2.A2003001.0005.051.2010313005421.hdf":mod04:Image_Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean >>2003a.txt
```

With the following content:

```
Driver: HDF4Image/HDF4 Dataset
Files: MOD04_L2.A2003001.0005.051.2010313005421.hdf
Size is 135, 204
Coordinate System is `'
GCP[  0]: Id=, Info=
          (0.5,0.5) -> (146.491271972656,2.82822823524475,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=, Info=
          (12.5,0.5) -> (150.015686035156,2.33101844787598,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=, Info=
          (24.5,0.5) -> (152.117935180664,2.02903413772583,0)
....
```

Note that the source file raster is not equidistant in WGS84, so the 4 corner coordinates are not sufficient, and thin plate spline interpolation is needed.

Additionally, the subdatasets

```
SUBDATASET_70_NAME=HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"MOD04_L2.A2003001.0005.051.2010313005421.hdf":0
SUBDATASET_70_DESC=[204x135] Longitude (32-bit floating-point)
SUBDATASET_71_NAME=HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"MOD04_L2.A2003001.0005.051.2010313005421.hdf":1
SUBDATASET_71_DESC=[204x135] Latitude (32-bit floating-point)
```

contain longitudes and latitudes as raster values.

Apart from that, you can use gdalwarp to extract the subdataset using those GCP points:

```
gdalwarp -of GTIFF -tps -t_srs EPSG:4326 HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD04_L2.A2003001.0005.051.2010313005421.hdf":mod04:Image_Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean 2003.tif
```

This file is already projected in WGS84.

---

**EDIT**

The second sample file you provide has a complete line of garbage at line 126.5. There is no way of automatically removing it, but you can create a VRT using gdal_translate, remove the false GCP entries manually from that, then gdalwarp to WGS84:

```
gdal_translate -of VRT HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD04_L2.A2011001.0030.051.2011001135339.hdf":mod04:Image_Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean 2011.vrt
(edit 2011.vrt)
gdalwarp -of GTIFF -tps 2011.vrt 2011-3.tif
```

The result still contains a blank line, but the rest is usable:

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

Another approach, that prevents GCP interpolation issues, is to export the data as XYZ file, and do the same with the longitude and latitude subdatasets:

```
gdal_translate -of XYZ HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:"MOD04_L2.A2011001.0030.051.2011001135339.hdf":mod04:Image_Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean 2011.xyz
gdal_translate -of XYZ HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"MOD04_L2.A2011001.0030.051.2011001135339.hdf":0 2011-lon.xyz
gdal_translate -of XYZ HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"MOD04_L2.A2011001.0030.051.2011001135339.hdf":1 2011-lat.xyz
```

These text files can be put together in a spreadsheet, and imported as delimited text layers using the lon and lat columns. The garbage coordinates get placed outside the globe, and can easily be cut with a +/- 180/90° cutline polygon. I took this as reference to find out how to use gdalwarp parameters correctly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Andre Joost, your approach is absolutely right. It turns out that the gdal package on my computer is out of date so I cannt get the GCPs via gdalinfo. I updated the gdal to 1.10.0 and now everythings work fine.

Comment: Testing with other sample data I found out that -tps option is required for the non-equidistant raster source. Otherwise your data gets slight offsets.

Comment: Hi Andre Joost, there are some files which some GCPs have value kind of (0.5,126.5) -> (-999,-999,0). Is it normal since if I gdalwarp those file, the output tif is extremely large (about 174mb) and cant be processed? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you give me an example file name? I would suggest to use the -refine_gcps option to filter those out.

Comment: example hdf file: http://sdrv.ms/1el4xCF
gdalinfo: http://sdrv.ms/1el4AOR
the subdataset is "mod04:Image_Optical_Depth_Land_And_Ocean"

Comment: Im using -refine_gcps to filter those dummy GCPs out, but dont know what is a best argument? I try -refine_gcps 200 but no help

Comment: I found no way to get -refine_gcps work well, but building a vrt is a good workaround. See my extended answer.