# Inaccurate alignment of MODIS HDF image (Dark Target product MYD04)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, modis, hdf

I have an issue with georeferencing of HDF files for the MYD04 product from MODIS (Dark Target Aerosol).

A sample HDF file is given in the following link -

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqq09649mbgfzmj/MYD04_L2.A2002187.1050.006.2014195211826.hdf?dl=1

Dragging and dropping the above file into QGIS, then choosing one of the layers, places it more or less in the right location. However, a closer look suggests the geo-referencing is not accurate. Seems like the image is a little too stretched. For example, note how the Gulf of Aqaba and the Nile river are misplaced -

[image]

Here is a zoomed-in view -

[image]

Two more things I tried -

1. using `gdal_translate` to convert from HDF to TIF with -

`gdal_translate -of GTiff \'HDF4_EOS:EOS_SWATH:MYD04_L2.A2002187.1050.006.2014195211826.hdf:mod04:Deep_Blue_Aerosol_Optical_Depth_550_Land\' modis.tif`

This works, but the resulting TIF image has exactly the same misplacement issue as when uploading the HDF into QGIS.

2. Reading the raster with R, using the `gdalUtils` package, in which case the extent information is not even being read and I see a rectangular image such as this -

[image]

3. I tried looking for something useful in the image metadata, attached here -

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qo379zbbkzut8cx/metadata.txt?dl=1

I see that it contains GCPs, which I have no idea how to use in a better way than what QGIS does.

My conclusion from all of this is that the HDF image is not reoreferenced via a rectangular extent (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax), but rather through some set of GCPs that require resampling. However I have no idea what is the cause for the geo-referencing problem - do QGIS and GDAL read the metadata in a wrong way? Are the GCPs inaccurate?

---

Following the valuable suggestions by **AndreJ** (see his comment), I used the 'lon' and 'lat' reference grid embedded in layers 71 & 72 of the HDF to create a point layer. Using R code as follows -

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(gdalUtils)

filename = "MYD04_L2.A2002187.1050.006.2014195211826.hdf"

# Subdataset
sds = get_subdatasets(filename)
s = sds[grepl("Deep_Blue_Aerosol_Optical_Depth_550_Land$", sds)]

# Values
r = s %>% readGDAL %>% raster

# Lon-Lat
lon = sds[71] %>% readGDAL %>% raster
lat = sds[72] %>% readGDAL %>% raster

# Stack
r = stack(lon, lat, r)
names(r) = c("lon", "lat", "value")

# To points
dat = as.data.frame(r)
dat = st_as_sf(dat, coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)
st_write(dat, "test.geojson")
```

Here is what the layer looks like, now correctly positioned -

[image]

Comment: gdal_translate does not use the GCP, nor the lat and lon bands in sds 0 and 1. You have to use gdalwarp instead. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81361/how-to-reproject-modis-swath-data-to-wgs84 for a full workflow.

Comment: Great, this solved the problem! Thank you very much