# SNPP Viirs swath data reprojection to wgs84

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, wgs84

How can I reproject this file:

I downloaded from: https://ufile.io/dev4b

ftp://nrt4.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/allData/5000/VNP14IMG_NRT/Recent/

I tried using gdal... but I'm not so expert, so can't do it... someone can help me?

I followed: [How to reproject MODIS Swath data to WGS84](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81361/how-to-reproject-modis-swath-data-to-wgs84)

But the file doesnt have GCP fields... I got this error:

```
"ERROR 1: Unable to compute a GCP_TPS based transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates for NETCDF:VNP14IMG_NRT.A2018163.0512.001.nc:fire mask."
```

Comment: Add your attempt at doing this using GDAL and tell us why it did not work, did you get an error message?

Comment: I followed this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81361/how-to-reproject-modis-swath-data-to-wgs84